# Store list of unique_ptrs, shared_ptrs, or IDs?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have classes that looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
private:
    int id;
    //Other data...
    std::list< ??? > connected_foo;
}

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
private:
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Foo> > all_foo;
}
```

In class `Foo`, I'm creating a graph-like structure, such that some `Foo` objects are linked to other `Foo` objects.

In C++11, which is most "correct"? Specifically, what should `???` be? A list of `unique_ptr`? A list of `shared_ptr`? Or a list of `int`, with a function to iterate through `all_foo` and find the specific object?

Or should I be using a different data structure all together (i.e.,  a`map`)? I know that the Boost libraries offer graphs, but that's a bit more than I'm looking for here (a.k.a. would like to stick to the C++ Standard Libraries).

If "correct" is too vague (probably is), assume the priorities are readability, least-likely-to-cause-memory-leaks, and conciseness, in that order.

A couple of notes: I'm fairly new to C++ (coming from C), so I'm attempting to not use C++ as "C with OO". In C, I'd use an array of pointers and call it a day most likely (especially since I know that the objects won't be freed until the program ends); the inability to create a copy of a `unique_ptr` is tripping me up a bit. The specific application I'm aiming for here is creating a circuit out of logic gates (using OO). And this is for a (grad) school project.

Comment: Please, never use `std::list` unless you know why you want to use it specifically. It has generally the worst performance of all the standard containers. If you just need a "list", your first choice should be `std::vector`.

Comment: @RobK - I went with `std::list` because I only ever need to iterate over it in one direction (from front to back), and I'll never need to access via index. Is it still the least performant in that case?

Comment: @RobK - Nevermind. Just read this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185222/what-is-the-point-of-using-lists-over-vectors-in-c

`std::vector` it is! :)

Comment: You may want to consider using a container of `std::weak_ptr<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably impossible to give an answer without knowing your full use-case. But if the `Bar` really owns all the `Foo`s and will outlive all of them (as you state in your question) I would propose:

```
std::vector<Foo*> connected_foo;
```

Nothing wrong with raw pointers - we're not using them to convey any ownership semantics, just observing.

Having a container of `unique_ptr<Foo>` is wrong - `Bar` already has unique ownership. You could make them `shared_ptr<Foo>` (and change `Bar` to share ownership). That would be correct, but if `Bar` really owns them it's unnecessary. Storing IDs instead means it's more expensive to do lookup, so I'm not sure that benefits anything.

Comment: Sounds good - apologies for the generality of the question, but adding a full use-case would probably triple the question's size (and be even less useful to others than it already is). Good to know that when ownership isn't being conveyed, raw pointers are still OK in C++ (though obviously I need to ensure the liveliness of what they point to, or include checks where they're used).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not going to iterate over all_foo and clear references in all objects each time you remove an object then you can use `std::list<std:weak_ptr<Foo>> connected_foo;` and check and update connected_foo on demand. Then when you want to use a connected foo in the node then you first lock it to be shared and check if it exists, if not exists you remove it from the list of connected. Note, you have to keep `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` in all_foo for that.